# SSL certificate: Invalid certificate chain

Tags: git, ssl, heroku

I am having a trouble when I try to `git push heroku master`. I am getting an error;

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://git.heroku.com/project-myproject.git/': SSL certificate problem: Invalid certificate chain
```

This problem occured from no where. I just closed my computer and opened then getting this error. I am running on MacOs Sierra 10.12.2

I have looked in to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/721778/can-not-clone-any-git-repository-from-github). But my certificate expires 10.11.2031.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do

git config --global http.sslVerify false